# Calling Stateful Class with simple alert dialog from another Class Flutter

Tags: class, flutter, dialog, stateful

I want to create a stateful class which has an alert dialog with content then how can i call it from another class. I am newbie in programming. Could you show with example code

Comment: what did you try ?

Answer (score 1):

Create a new dart file `my_alerts.dart` and define it as a `library`. You can then import the `showSampleDialog` function from it and use it in any class. Just pass the `context` from the class that is using it.

For more info about alerts see this [article](https://medium.com/@nils.backe/flutter-alert-dialogs-9b0bb9b01d28)

```html
library my_alerts;

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

// user defined function
void showSampleDialog(BuildContext context) {
  // flutter defined function
  showDialog(
    context: context,
    builder: (BuildContext context) {
      // return object of type Dialog
      return AlertDialog(
        title: new Text("Alert Dialog title"),
        content: new Text("Alert Dialog body"),
        actions: <Widget>[
          // usually buttons at the bottom of the dialog
          new FlatButton(
            child: new Text("Close"),
            onPressed: () {
              Navigator.of(context).pop();
            },
          ),
        ],
      );
    },
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Tomas answer is the way to go.

Here a running example:
https://dartpad.dartlang.org/638db165becbe88b25bbd9c77f636297